# Type trait to match signatures of member functions of different classes

Tags: c++, qt, metaprogramming, c++17, type-traits

What is most elegant way (possibly C++17-way) to check if signatures of two methods defined in two different classes are exactly the same?

For example:

```
template< typename ...Ts >
struct A
{
    void f(Ts...);
};

template< typename ...Ts >
struct B
{
    void g(Ts...);
};

static_assert(has_same_signatures< decltype(&A<>::f), decltype(&B<>::g) >{});
static_assert(!has_same_signatures< decltype(&A< int >::f), decltype(&B< char >::g) >{});
//static_assert(has_same_signatures< decltype(&A< void >::f), decltype(&B<>::g) >{}); // don't know is it feasible w/o extra complexity
```

It would be great, if types of non-member functions on either side would be allowed too.

Maybe result type should be entangled too.

The task origins from common problem of matching signal/slot signatures in *Qt* framework.

Comment: @Barry Don't think, that ampersands needed. Do you think, that references to functions are not good enough?

Comment: You can't refer to a non-static member function without the `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
// static member functions / free functions are the same
// if their types are the same
template <class T, class U>
struct has_same_signature : std::is_same<T, U> { };

// member functions have the same signature if they're two pointers to members
// with the same pointed-to type
template <class T, class C1, class C2>
struct has_same_signature<T C1::*, T C2::*> : std::true_type { };
```

Note that `A<void>` is simply ill-formed as you can't have a parameter of type `void`.

Comment: "signature" doesn't include `noexcept`-ness or the return type, but the function type does (`noexcept`-ness since C++17); meanwhile, the function type doesn't include *requires-clause* in C++20, but "signature" does. OP needs to specify more precisely what they want.

Comment: Where are parameters types? I see only asterisks. Is it enough?

Comment: @T.C. Ha, this is a much deeper hole than I expected.

Comment: @Orient In your example `decltype(&A<>::f)` is `void (A::*)()` which is also `void() A::*`, so `T` would deduce as `void()`.

Comment: @Barry Interesting notation. In light of this notation is this `template <class T, class C1, class C2, class ...Ts> struct has_same_signature<T (C1::*)(Ts...), T (C2::*)(Ts...)> : std::true_type { };` overengeneered?

Comment: @Orient It's not overengineered - it's actually less complete. Your version only matches non-cv-qualified, non-ref-qualified, non-varargs member functions without noexcept-specifiers. Mine matches everything.

Comment: @T.C. After revealing new facts I think, that I can't formulate the question more clearly. Because there is only the need of `is_convertible` per function argument check in the source problem. But the problem itself is interesting